# How to translate this MySQL-Query into a Hibernate-Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, geolocation, spatial

I'd like to ask how to translate this MySQL query into a Hibernate query:

```
SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE WITHIN(GeomFromText('POINT(52.5 13.3)'), polygon);
```

or this

```
SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE MBRContains(polygon, GeomFromText('POINT(52.5 13.3)');
```

Thank you.
Thomas

Comment: What do these clauses mean `WITHIN(GeomFromText('POINT(52.5 13.3)'), polygon);` and `MBRContains(polygon, GeomFromText('POINT(52.5 13.3)');
`?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/geometry-property-functions.html

Comment: I don't think native Hibernate does but check out http://www.hibernatespatial.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import javax.persistence.Query;

Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(52.5, 13.3);
Point point = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(coord);
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM Cities WHERE WITHIN(:location, polygon) = true", Cities.class);
query.setParameter("location", point);
```